# Probability on regular graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, optimization

I have to prove or find a conterexample for the following statement:

> Given a regular UNDIRECTED graph $G=(V,E)$ and an integer $d>0$, the probability distribution $\mu$ over $V$ minimizing the probability that $d$ i.i.d. vertexes drawn from $\mu$ are in the neighbouhood of the same node is the uniform distribution on $V$.

The question arises from a very specific problem, where

- $V$ subsets of $\{0,\dots N\}$ with cardinality $k$
- Two subsets are linked if they share at least one element

therefore, in my case there are $\binom{N}{k}$ vertexes, such that every vertex $v$ is connected to $\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n-k}{k}-1$ other vetexes. Also a proof only in this setting would be very very appriciated.